# Rewrite images from sub domains to root domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

For one of my projects I need the images on my server which are in the /assets folder be available under a subdomain.

For example:
https://www.example.com/assets/picture.jpg should be accessible through
https://subdomain.example.com/assets/picture.jpg

I've added this to .htaccess, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^!www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /assets/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/assets/%1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

This also didn't work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^!www\.example\.com[NC]
RewriteRule ^/assets/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/assets/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: If both http hosts ("domain" and "subdomain") are served by the same http server (I only assume that, you did not say), then you don't need to do any rewriting at all. You just have to define both http hosts (or one virtual host that acts as a default host responding to the host you call "subdomain"). If both http hosts share the same `DOCUMENT_ROOT` inside the server side file system things will work out of the box. Otherwise you can use an `Alias` command to map the `/assets` folder into the path space.

Comment: "Redirecting" doesn't seem to make sense either? Are you not linking directly to the assets via the main domain?

Comment: The domain and subdomain are on the same server. Can you give me an example of how I map that /assets folder using the Alias command?

Answer (score 0):

If your domain and subdomain share the same `public_html`, you don't have to do anything, like `@arkascha` said in the comment. It will work by default.

I suppose your example.com and subdomain.example.com don't share the same public_html. In this situation, the `.htaccess` from your subdomain.example.com will be different from the one on example.com. You have to add the rule below in the `.htacess` from the subdomain root:

```
# .htaccess from the subdomain.example.com root

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/assets/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

This redirects all requests that start with assets to the assets from the main domain.

---

A second solution, without `.htaccess`, is to make a symlink from your subdomains assets folder to the domain assets folder. On Linux the command can look like this:

```
ln -sf /public_html/assets /public_html/subdomain/assets
```

On windows it is called junction link (also called a soft link).